# How to release entire UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an iPhone application, and I have included a virtual "timeout" for being in the background. When it enters the background, I make a timestamp. When it re-enters, i compare the current time to the timestamp. This all works great.

What I want is for the application to basically reset like it was just launched. Everything in my application lives inside of a UINavigationController, so I thought I could just release it and everything inside, then reallocate it and start over. Is there a right way to do this? I have a feeling that if i just "release" the UINavigationController, all of the ViewControllers inside will just leak into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just release your `UINavigationController`, and if your `ViewControllers` are only retained by your `UINavigationController`, which should be the case, then they will also get deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

You may reset your model data manually and then return to start screen of your app by
`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a sensible way you need to reset your controllers and data model to the state you want (e.g. as if your app was just launched). I'd also do this in a way that looks natural for your users. Something like the following:

1. Load a splash screen view (or something temporary) in the main app window.
2. Release your navigation controller (more generally, release the top level controller owning the view previously added to the window). this will release all associated controllers and views assuming you haven't retained them anywhere else.
3. You may also need to handle any modal views that were displayed when your app went into the background. You can either dismiss them automatically when the app goes into the background or keep state around to dismiss them when the app resumes and you are resetting it).
4. Reset your data model to the state you want
5. Recreate your navigation controller and add it back to the window and release the temporary splash screen.